# How do you counter the wobble of spinning ring world filled with ocean?

Tags: internal-consistency, space-constructs, geostationary-orbit

I imagine a bicycle spoke rim scaled up a thousand time orbiting a star, the side of rim facing the star will experience more pull therefore more water... assuming its spin axis is along the orbital plane. I kept thinking should we omit the spoke altogether so it will be a floating donut in space and it can wobble however it wants without a cause for concern right?

Comment: You could mount it on four World Elephants (a fifth might slip and crash into the disc) who in turn stand on a world turtle who swims through space. If the disc wobbles you make the Elephants lift or lower the disc on that side to stabilize it.

Comment: @Demigan: the problem is these elephants like to play Frisbee and the world turtle would alway miss... GG

Comment: Unless your ring is unusually large and/or close to the star, there won't be any significant difference in gravity from one side to the other. For instance, at the closest Earth passes to the Sun, its near side is 0.004% nearer, meaning solar gravity is 0.0000002% stronger on that side.

Comment: So would the error grows exponentially with time... I likes to press panic button every now and then, second nature.

Comment: Do you mean a ring orbiting like a planet or do you mean a ring that surrounds the star with star being in the middle of it?

Comment: @JANXOL: if you are referring to Dyson ring then no

Comment: You really need to describe your ring in more detail first, there are a lot of different things that could be called ring worlds. on a Niven style ringworld the side facing the star is the only one with water because you spin the ring for gravity.

Comment: If the spin axis is "along" the orbital plane, your ring is spinning like a coin flip, and I'm sure that's not what you want. Instead, you want the spin axis [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) to the orbital plane.

Comment: They're trying to close your question for lack of details right now: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/close/74724 so I suggest you expand on it a bit before that happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A wheel the size of a bicycle rim "scaled up a thousand times", is only about 620m in diameter.

In an Earth-like orbit around the sun, the part closer to the sun will experience gravity that is $4.21\cdot 10^{-9}$ stronger than the part that is furthest from the sun.

I don't expect a large slosh from a 1 part in 237 000 000 gravity wobble.

Let's assume you made a typo, and intended to ask for a "one **billion** times scaled up" wheel.
Then gravity on the wheel side nearer the sun is now 0.42 percent higher than on the far side. You might get a slosh, about 1/15th as big as Earth's lunar tides. Which will be rather trivial, in a wheel with a size twice as big as the orbit of the Moon around Earth.

Answer (score 2):

**Water is always on the far side.**

Your water flows: a great river.  The bulk of it stays opposite to the star such that low water is always on the side nearest the star and high water on the side farthest away.  This is also a fine way to equalize pull on the structure as a whole, which even without water is (probably, assuming typo in OP!) large enough to experience tidal forces.

How does the water move?  Perhaps the banks squeeze and heave peristaltically?  Jets?  Your people were clever enough to build this thing; they can figure out the water also.